# Scrolling the height of several divs by several buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with the following structure:

```
<div id="about" class="section">
    <div class="button">
        <img src="/images/arrow.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="films" class="section">
    <div class="button">
        <img src="/images/arrow.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="projects" class="section">
    <div class="button">
        <img src="/images/arrow.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like that when clicking on the image, you will be scrolled to the end of the `<div>` where the `<img>`is located.

I have stated with this code but it works only for the first image.

```
function go_to(){
    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: $('.section').height()}, 900, "easeInOutExpo");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
      var go_to_div = $('.button img');
     $(go_to_div).click(function(event) {
        go_to() 
     });
});
```

If necessary, I can change the HTML structure. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for `scrollTop` property, you need to give a value to go there. Your `$('.section').height()` code allways gives the same value so it kinda stuck. Try this instead

```
function go_to(section){
    var pos = section.position();
    $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: section.height() + pos.top}, 900, "easeInOutExpo");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button img').click(function(event) {
    go_to($(this).closest(".section"));
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8L092cfc/)

Comment: Thanks! works like charm! I just didn't understand how the first part of the code work. How does `section.position()` target the right class? since we don't declare it like `$('.section').position()`...

Comment: @LessandMoreCollective in `$('.button img').click()` function we send `$(this).closest(".section")` to the `go_to()` function as a parameter. That's how it knows which section it is gonna be.